# Find Proxy IP address used by Android app

Tags: internet, proxy

I use the "Proxy Browser For Android" app on the android platform, developed by Abhinav Singh.

It uses a proxy to enable the user to browse anonymously.

I really wish to know the ip address used by the app.

My question is: How do you closely monitor the internet traffic on an Android ?

I am an Android developer, so I use ADB to connect Android to the pc, and issue commands to android from the pc. Is there an ADB command that I can use to see internet traffic or even get logs etc ? If not, then, is there an app for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to monitor Android internet traffic is to connect it to a Wi-Fi network and run Wireshark on the router. That way, you can do whatever you like on the Android device while watching the packets go past on the Wi-Fi router.

An on-device solution can be less convenient, because you have to do the activity you want to monitor, then switch to the monitoring app to see the results. In addition, you need to have [root](/questions/tagged/root) on the device to monitor other apps' network traffic. In some cases this can change the behaviour of the app you want to monitor, though I don't expect that'll be a problem for you. [Network Log](https://code.google.com/p/iptableslog/) is an open-source example of an on-device network logging/monitoring app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've found this to setup wiresharp on wireless lan,http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN , but could you perhaps explain it in an easy way ?

Comment: @Dv_MH That would go a little beyond the scope of this site. We try our best to help out with specific Android questions, but rewriting the existing documentation for a non-Android tool is going a bit too far. I suggest you try it out yourself, and if you get stuck, see if anyone in the Wireshark community is willing to spend their time on this.